# Understanding Breakpoint function: how for loops work inside functions

Tags: r

I have the following exercise to be solved in R. Under the exercise, there is a hint towards the solution.

**Exercise:** If there are no ties in the data set, the function above will produce breakpoints with h observations in the interval between two consecutive breakpoints (except the last two perhaps). If there are ties, the function will by construction return unique breakpoints, but there may be more than h observations in some intervals.

**Hint:**

```
my_breaks <-function(x, h = 5) {
  x <-sort(x)
  breaks <- xb <- x[1]
  k <- 1
  for(i in seq_along(x)[-1]) 
  {if(k<h) 
  {k <- k+1}
    else{
      if(xb<x[i-1]&&x[i-1]<x[i]) 
      {xb <- x[i-1]
        breaks <-c(breaks, xb)
        k <- 1
      }
    }
    }
```

However, I am having a hard time understanding the above function particularly the following lines

```
for(i in seq_along(x)[-1]) 
  {if(k<h) 
  {k <- k+1}
```

**Question**:
How is the for loop supposed to act in k if k is previously defined as 1 and i is different than k? How are the breakpoints chosen according to the h=5 gap if the for loop is not acting on x? Can someone explain to me how this function works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the question. k is never being compared to i, and appears to be a counter that guarantees the gap between a breakpoint is at least h. The loop is still acting on x, just indirectly through `seq_along` which generates indices

Comment: @petrucci4prez        I am not understanding how there is a  "counter that guarantees the gap between a breakpoint is at least h". I cannot see it. Can you elaborate on that? That is precisely my question or doubt. Thanks!

Comment: @petrucci4prez k is defined as 1. Why do they write an if statement with k<-k+1? How does that interfere with the gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that your example is incomplete. The return value and the final brace are missing there. Here is the correct version.

```
my_breaks <-function(x, h = 5) {
  x <- sort(x)
  breaks <- xb <- x[1]
  k <- 1
  for(i in seq_along(x)[-1]){
    if(k<h) {
      k <- k+1
    } else {
      if(xb<x[i-1]&&x[i-1]<x[i]){
        xb <- x[i-1]
        breaks <-c(breaks, xb)
        k <- 1
      }
    }
  }
  breaks
}
```

Let's check if it works.

```
my_breaks(c(1,1,1:5,8:10), 2)
#[1] 1 2 4 8

my_breaks(c(1,1,1:5,8:10), 5)
#[1] 1 3
```

As you can see, everything is fine. And what is `seq_along(x)[-1]`? We could write this equation as `2:length(x)`. So the `for` loop goes through each element of the vector `x` in sequence, skipping the first element.
What is the `k` variable for? It counts the distance to take into account the `h` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My problem regards the understanding of what the variable k is for. k is defined as 1.  How does k interact with x? What does it mean to have k bigger or smaller than h. There is no line like x[k]

Comment: The variable `k` is nothing more than a simple numerator which counts `k<-k+1` here. It is not a pointer to the vector `x`. The values of the `x` vector are checked here `if(xb<x[i-1]&&x[i-1]<x[i])`. And that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! What happens if k<h, which I think it is once k=1? Does it mean breaks=x[1]?

Comment: How does it count? Is it not k a constant?

Comment: Why would not i instead of k make sense? Does the for loop iterates k?

Comment: Read the program with understanding!
1. The `for` loop iterates over the `i` variable - `for (and in ...` 
2. The variable `k` is incremented until  is less than `h` - `if(k<h){k<-k+1...`
3. The variable `k` will be set to 1 if `xb<x[i-1]&&x[i-1]<x[i] `is true.

Comment: Please have a look at this page https://rpubs.com/MarekFiolka/808269. I have described to you as precisely as possible how it works.

Comment: I am very grateful for the detailed answer in the link. It is a great help to learn R. Thank you so much!